# query linq about 2 lists group by

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following query in linq, which takes 2 lists as a data source. The first contains a list of ProductID and its description

```
   public class Venta
{
    public string ProductoId { get; set; }
    public string clienteRut { get; set; }
}

public class Ventas
{
    public List<Venta> lstVentas { get; set; }
}
```

and the other list has the products sold

```
public class Productos
{
    public List<Producto> lstProductos { get; set; }
}
public class Producto
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to consult the 5 most sold products, ordered by quantity from the most sold, to the least sold.

So far I have the following linq query, but I do not know how to do it so that I am given the list of the first 5, ordered from highest to lowest based on the quantity (cont)

```
        Venta vta1 = new Venta();
        vta1.ProductoId = "1";
        vta1.clienteRut = "121370654";

        Venta vta2 = new Venta();
        vta2.ProductoId = "2";
        vta2.clienteRut = "121370654";

        Venta vta3 = new Venta();
        vta3.ProductoId = "3";
        vta3.clienteRut = "121370654";


        List<Venta> lstVentasDia = new List<Venta>();
        lstVentasDia.Add(vta1);
        lstVentasDia.Add(vta2);
        lstVentasDia.Add(vta3);

        VentasDia vtas = new VentasDia();
        vtas.date = "2018-05-01";
        vtas.lstVentas = lstVentasDia;


        var Lista5Top = from vendidos in vtas.lstVentas
                        orderby vendidos.ProductoId
                        group vendidos by vendidos.ProductoId into Grupo
                        select new { key = Grupo.Key, cont = Grupo.Count() };
```

I need in addition to that group of result, add the name of the product that is in the list Products, and order it by quantity sold of greater to less only the first 5

Thankful in advance
Gloria

Comment: vtas.1stSales does not exist in your defined classes

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Is product ID the number of times the item was sold - or as its name suggests the ID of the product.

Comment: Because you need or order by the times it was sold not by its ID

Comment: After grouping, order it by the `cont` property of the anonymous type. You do not need to order by `ProductId`

Comment: Then finish up with a .Take(5) It might be take - lowercase T in C#

Comment: I'm sorry guys, I do not speak English so I translated my question into the Google translator. and the source code was modified. I have already fixed the correct code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following :

```
            Productos productos = new Productos();

            var Lista5Top = (from vendidos in vtas.lstVentas
                             join prod in productos.lstProductos on vendidos.ProductoId equals prod.id
                             select new { id = vendidos.ProductoId, rut = vendidos.clienteRut, name = prod.name })
                             .OrderBy(x => x.id)
                             .GroupBy(x => x.id)
                             .Select(x => new { id = x.Key, cont = x.Count(), name = x.FirstOrDefault().name })
                             .OrderByDescending(x => x.cont)
                             .Take(5).ToList();
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help. As you indicate it works correctly, I get the list grouped by the number of products sold, from the most sold to the least sold and only the first 5. I just need one detail, and that is that I need to incorporate in the result, the name of the product that is in the Product class. How is this field added between the ProductID and the count?

Comment: @Gloria, this person is kind enough to solve your initial issue, please be kind enough to upvote his answer, before requesting more information

Comment: Thanks so much for u help jdweng. Have a nice day